# How do I make background image fade from grayscale to color on load?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, animation, fade

I currently have a Bootstrap webpage with a color background image.
I want the image to start out grayscale and then gradually fade into color once the page loads (not hover).

What is the best way to do this with CSS/HTML?

Comment: First post? Welcome to StackOverflow.  Check out [using CSS to convert color images to black and white...](http://thenewcode.com/532/Convert-Images-To-Black-And-White-With-CSS) Then tell us what you've tried.  Hint: JSFiddle is really the best tool to display a small piece of code.  Easy for somebody to help you...

Comment: You can't do that with a background image in CSS.

Comment: @Paulie_D   What's a background, image, really?  Okay, so we have a div with an image in it, and a low Z-index.  Will that work for you?

Comment: It's an image that is in the CSS and not the HTML.

Answer (score 2):

You could achieve this with CSS keyframe animations.

You would want to expand on the following:

```
@keyframes greyscale-fade-in {
    0%   { -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); }
    100% { -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%); }
}


.image-selector {
    animation: greyscale-fade-in 1s ease-in forwards;
}
```

The keyframes control how you want the image to be adapted as the page loads.

The `animation` value needs to be told which keyframes to use (`greyscale-fade-in`), how long you want the animation to last for (`1s` is 1 second), what time of transition you would like (`ease-in`).

The `forwards` parameter tells the animation to only run from 0% to 100% and not to go back from 100% to 0%.

The animation rule needs to be applied to a selector that targets your image, so make sure your `<img>` or the wrapper `<div>` has a class that you can target.

For more information on animations, you should read: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation

Comment: Thats a great solution! - was trying to come up with a solution myself but then tested yours out and it worked great. Made a fiddle if anyone is curious https://jsfiddle.net/26zpq6vc/6/ but full cred to you for that one